# Python fast duplicate detection, can I store only the hash but not the value

Tags: python, hash, duplicates, set, sparse-matrix

I have a method for creating an image "hash" which is useful for duplicate frame detection. (Doesn't really matter for the question)

Currently I put each frame of a video in a set, and can do things like find videos that contain intersections by comparing the sets. (I have billions of hashes)

Since I have my own "hash" I don't need the values of the set, only the ability to detect duplicate items.

This would reduce my memory footprint by like half (since I would only have the hashes).

I know internally a set is actually hash,value pairs. There must be a way to make a "SparseSet" or a "hashonly" set.

Something like

```
2 in sparset(1,2,3) 

True
```

but where

```
for s in sparset(1,2,3)
```

would return nothing, or hashes not values.

Comment: You are talking about two different types of hashes, one identifies the frame and one is used for efficient lookup in the set.

Comment: Sets store the whole shebang. Just make your hash be an object whose`__hash__`  method just returns `self`

Comment: The hashes aren’t guaranteed to be unique, though, and aren’t stored. Are you using a cryptographic hash or something? What type of object, exactly, goes in the set?

Comment: Make sure your hashes extend int

Answer (score 1):

That's not *quite* how sets work. Both the hash value and the value are required, because the values must be checked for equality in case of a hash collision.

If you don't care about collisions, you can use a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) instead of a set. These are very memory efficient, but give probabilistic answers (either definitely not in the set, or maybe in the set). There's no Bloom filter in the standard library, but there are several implementations on PyPI.

If you care more about optimizing space than time, you could just keep the hashes in a list and then when you need to check for an element, sort it in place and do a binary search. Python's [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is very efficient when the list is mostly sorted already, so subsequent sorts will be relatively fast. Python lists have a `sort()` method and you can implement a binary search fairly easily using the standard library `bisect` module.

You can combine both techniques, i.e. don't bother sorting if the Bloom filter indicates the element is not in the set. And of course, don't bother sorting again if you haven't added any elements since last time.

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. Is there a python built-in I am missing, or do I have to construct my own? 

(at which point I am kind of looking at my gimped set, since I think based on how a set works that it might already be using a bloom, and then checking the possibly-ins to see if they are actually-ins)